# Windows Phone ReverseGeocoding to get Address from Lat and Long

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, reverse-geocoding, service-reference

i am using the following service reference to get location details from latitude and longnitude

http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/geocodeservice.svc

i added the above URL to my Service reference class and try to get the location details by calling the below method

```
 public void reverse()
       {
           string Results = "";
           try
           {
               // Set a Bing Maps key before making a request
               string key = "Bing Maps Key";

               ReverseGeocodeRequest reverseGeocodeRequest = new ReverseGeocodeRequest();

               // Set the credentials using a valid Bing Maps key
               reverseGeocodeRequest.Credentials = new GeoCodeService.Credentials();
               reverseGeocodeRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = key;

               // Set the point to use to find a matching address
               GeoCodeService.Location point = new GeoCodeService.Location();
               point.Latitude = 47.608;
               point.Longitude = -122.337;

               reverseGeocodeRequest.Location = point;

               // Make the reverse geocode request
               GeocodeServiceClient geocodeService = new GeocodeServiceClient();
               **GeocodeResponse geocodeResponse = geocodeService.ReverseGeocode(reverseGeocodeRequest);**



           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Results = "An exception occurred: " + ex.Message;

           }
```

but i am getting the following error message

1. GeoCodeService.GeoCodeServiceClient does not contain a definition for ReverseGeocode and no extension method
2. GeoCodeService.GeoCodeServiceClient could not be found.

help me in solving the problem.and also tell me is this a best way to find location details .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8 you have built-in API for reverse geocoding, without the need of adding a Service Reference to Bing Maps:

```
        List<MapLocation> locations;
        ReverseGeocodeQuery query = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
        query.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(47.608, -122.337);
        query.QueryCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error == null && e.Result.Count > 0)
                {
                    locations = e.Result as List<MapLocation>;
                    // Do whatever you want with returned locations. 
                    // e.g. MapAddress address = locations[0].Information.Address;
                }
            };
        query.QueryAsync();
```

Comment: i tried it but some times it it giving the result very fast and some times it taking long time to fetch the result

Comment: Take into account, that both, your approach, and mine, query external servers to get the result. They depend on the network connection.

Comment: yes you are right, the below method is taking long time                                                                       Geoposition currentPosition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));  to give latitude and longnitude is there any alternative to find device current location

Comment: But, what is taking time, getting the current positon, or doing the reverse geocode query?

Comment: getting the current position using                          Geoposition currentPosition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

Comment: Does it happen in both, emulator and real devices? Only in first call, or always? Since this does nothing to do with the  reverse geocode query, you could post a separate question, and see if someone could help you.

Comment: can i use GeoCoordinateWatcher to find latitude and longnitude

Comment: Yes, you can use both, .NET and WinPRT apis.