# How to convert antipode (lat,lang) to address in my Wp8 c# project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, geolocation

İ am need some help, i am use watcher to find my location. And i'm find my antipode click button with watcher coordinates. But i am need find antipodes address neares territory. İ am search this question: [How to convert longitude and latitude value to address in windows phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613578/how-to-convert-longitude-and-latitude-value-to-address-in-windows-phone)
but i' am try ReverseGeocodeQuery query = new ReverseGeocodeQuery(); command and i have this error when debug :
"+      e   {System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs} System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs" (query.QueryAsync() command line error)

i am want to convert lat,lang to adress information.

İnformation:
antipode is aplication bar button(use for find antipode and adress)

and my capabilities

```
  <Capabilities>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_AUDIO" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MAP" />
    </Capabilities>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using MapCalismasi.Resources;
using System.Device.Location;
using Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Services;
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
using System.Text;


namespace MapCalismasi
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        GeoCoordinateWatcher watch;
        public GeoCoordinate konum = null;


        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (watch == null)
            {
                watch = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High)
                {
                    MovementThreshold=10
                };

                watch.Start();
                watch.PositionChanged += watch_PositionChanged;



            }



        }

    void watch_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>KonumUpdate(e));

    }

    void KonumUpdate(GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        try
        {
            konum = new GeoCoordinate(e.Position.Location.Latitude, e.Position.Location.Longitude);
            map1.SetView(konum, 15, MapAnimationKind.Parabolic);

            map1.Layers.Clear();
            MapLayer maplayer = new MapLayer();
            if (konum != null)
            {
                DrawPos(konum, maplayer);
            }
            map1.Layers.Add(maplayer);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Dont find location");

        }

    }
    private void DrawPos(GeoCoordinate coordinate, MapLayer mapLayer) 
    {
        MapOverlay overlayp=new MapOverlay();
        CurrentPosition currentpos = new CurrentPosition();
        currentpos.Poiimg.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(@"images\poi2.png", UriKind.Relative));
        currentpos.Tag = new GeoCoordinate(coordinate.Latitude, coordinate.Longitude);
        overlayp.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(coordinate.Latitude, coordinate.Longitude);
        overlayp.Content = currentpos;
        overlayp.PositionOrigin = new Point(0, .3);
        mapLayer.Add(overlayp);
    }

    private void DrawAnt(GeoCoordinate coordinate, MapLayer mapLayer)
    {
        MapOverlay overlayp = new MapOverlay();
        CurrentPosition currentpos = new CurrentPosition();
        currentpos.Poiimg.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(@"images\poi1.png", UriKind.Relative));
        currentpos.Tag = new GeoCoordinate(coordinate.Latitude, coordinate.Longitude);
        overlayp.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(coordinate.Latitude, coordinate.Longitude);
        overlayp.Content = currentpos;
        overlayp.PositionOrigin = new Point(0, .3);
        mapLayer.Add(overlayp);
    }

    private void antipode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //error path
    {

        Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
        geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.Default;



        double en=watch.Position.Location.Latitude;
        double boy=watch.Position.Location.Longitude;
        if (en > 0 )
        {
            en = -watch.Position.Location.Latitude;

        }
        else if (en < 0 )
        {
            en =Math.Abs(watch.Position.Location.Latitude);

        }
        else if (en == 0 )
        {

            en =0;
        }

        if (boy < 0)
        {
            boy = (watch.Position.Location.Longitude +180);

        }
        else if (boy==0)
        {
            boy = 0;
        }
        else if(boy > 0)
        {
            boy = (watch.Position.Location.Longitude -180);
        }
        konum = new GeoCoordinate(en, boy);                
        map1.SetView(konum, 15, MapAnimationKind.Parabolic);


        map1.Layers.Clear();
        MapLayer maplayerr = new MapLayer();
        if (konum != null)
        {
            DrawAnt(konum, maplayerr);
        }
        map1.Layers.Add(maplayerr);

        ReverseGeocodeQuery query = new ReverseGeocodeQuery(); 
        query.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(en, boy); 
        query.QueryCompleted += query_QueryCompleted;
         query.QueryAsync(); //error path if delete this line dont error



    }

    void query_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>> e)
    {
        string address; //error path
        address = e.Result[0].Information.Address.Street; 
    }



    private void zoomin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (map1.ZoomLevel < 20)
        {
            map1.ZoomLevel = map1.ZoomLevel + 1; 
        }

    }

    private void zoomout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (map1.ZoomLevel > 1)
        {
            map1.ZoomLevel = map1.ZoomLevel-1;                
        }          


    }





} }
```

Comment: Do you have all the required capabilities? Specifically you need ID_CAP_MAP for ReverseGeocodeQuery()

Comment: Thanks for answering firstly, 
  <Capabilities>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_AUDIO" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MAP" />
    </Capabilities>
my capabilies is this