# How to assign geographic location to a string windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation, maps

I'm trying to find a way of getting a devices geographic location and set it to a string variable in windows phone 7.1 development.I'm sure there is a simple way of acheiving this in this SDK but I haven't found any solution worth while yet.I have done something similar in Android before by including the Google maps api and getting a key but I'm not sure how to do it with windows phone.Can someone point me in the correct direction with this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for ReverseGeoCoding.

What ReverseGeoCoding does is, It gets the GeoCoordinates of the current location and then transforms the geocoordinates into the readable address which could be easily assigned to a string.

Its a bit lengthy procedure for a developer who targets Windows phone 7 for the purpose as there are no built in methods available to do so.

However, you need to get your app registered with BING api so that you could get a service key which could help you in the problems like ReverseGeoCoding or GeoCoding.

But, If you make the target OS as 8 then its not that difficult. There are built in service calls which could help ou solve our problem without the need of making the hands dirty on registration.

fore more, refer

Link [One](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/8f59dfdb-b445-4102-94db-5680d47075c0/reverse-geocoding-in-wp7?forum=wpdevelop)

Link [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685088/windows-phone-reversegeocoding-to-get-address-from-lat-and-long)